# Only first Nvidia card detected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, pci-express

Motherboard is a BIOSTAR Z270GT9 with three GeForce GTX 1060s (in PCIe x16 slot 1, 3, and 5). All of the cards are on USB powered riser cards, if that's relevant. I have Ubuntu Server 14.04 installed with gnome. The first and second card both have HDMI monitors connected. I installed nvidia-367 for the drivers through apt-get.

Only the first card seems to work and is detected in the system. I tried looking through the BIOS to see if there were any PCI related settings, and I could not find any. The fans are all running on the cards and so are the lights.

Here is my output for 'lspci | grep -i nvidia':

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 (rev a1)
```

Here is my output for 'dmesg | grep NVRM':

```
[    3.610776] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.66  Mon May  1 15:29:16 PDT 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
[    4.760621] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[    4.760624] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[    4.760625] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[    4.760626] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[    4.760627] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
```

I'm unsure of what to look for next.